# If Statement with And operator condition in AT&T Assembly

Tags: if-statement, assembly, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

How would I go about doing an if statement with and operator as its condition in `AT&T Assembly`?

```
assume x = 0x60
assume y = 0x45
```

For example:

```
if(x and y)
    //do something
```

Would this the correct code for it?

```
.globl func

func:
    push %r10     //r10 = x
    push %r11     //r11 = y
    movq $0x60, %r10        
    movq $0x45, %r11
    jmp .loop

.loop:
     movq %r10, %r12
     and $r11, %r12
     cmpq $0xFF, %r12
     je .if
     jmp .done
.if:
     //Do something here
     jmp .done     
.done:
    pop %r10     //r10 = x
    pop %r11     //r11 = y
    ret
```

Comment: Is your `and` operator bitwise and or logic and?

Answer (score 0):

**Code review:**

Your code is massively overcomplicated.  (But that's normal for beginners; if you look back at this once you have some more experience in asm you'll say the same thing.)

**You don't need to save/restore r10 or r11**: functions are allowed to clobber them.  i.e. they're call-clobbered.  Normally you'd use "legacy" registers like eax/rax and edx/rdx (with 32-bit operand size because your numbers are small) to save code size.  But you can worry about saving REX prefixes later; r10 and r11 are fine.

**You don't need any `jmp` instructions.**  `jmp` to the next line is redundant and a no-op: execution falls through to the next line on its own, whether there's a label there or not.

You only need one `je` or `jne` to skip over the `.if` block if the condition is false.

---

#### The if branching

Your `and/cmp` condition doesn't make sense for boolean or bitwise `and`.  Why is it true only if all 8 bits are set?  SSE2 SIMD instructions like `pcmpeqb` produce 0 or 0xFF compare-result, but there's no instruction that produces `0xFF` iff both of the input operands are non-zero.  (So what you've implemented is `if ((x&y) == 0xFF)`

For bitwise, `if(x & y)`, use `test %r10,%r11 / jz .done`.  For boolean, test-and-branch on x being non-zero (`test %r10,%r10 / jz .done`, then repeat for y.

```
.globl bitwise_and     # args:  x in RDI,   y in RSI
bitwise_and:           # x86-64 System V calling convention

    test  %rdi, %rsi     # set flags according to x&y
    jz    .Lfalse        # skip the next block if (x&y) == 0
        # if condition was true, fall into the if block

    .Lfalse:
    ret
```

Or for boolean

```
.globl boolean_and     # args:  x in RDI,   y in RSI
boolean_and:

    test  %rdi, %rdi
    jz    .Lfalse
    test  %rsi, %rsi
    jz    .Lfalse
        # if condition was true, fall into the if block

    .Lfalse:
    ret
```

x86 unfortunately doesn't have a very nice way to use only one branch instruction to check if either input is zero.  Checking each input separately like the short-circuit behaviour of C's `x && y` operator is what compilers often do.

For `x || y`, it's much better: `x || y` is true in the same cases when `x | y` is true, so we can just do `or  %rdi, %rsi`, which sets flags according to the result.  Then `jz` to skip over the `if` block if the OR result was zero.